# How create two dimensional associative array in jquery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to create two dimensional array with jQuery and get following result:

```
Array(
  [data_name_1] => Array([0] => A, [1] => B)
  [data_name_2] => Array([0] => P, [1] => L) 
  [data_name_3] => Array([0] => K, [1] => M) 
)
```

The HTML is

```
<li data-attr-name="data_name_1">
   <div class="_container_">
       <span>A</span>
       <span>B</span>
   </div>
</li>
<li data-attr-name="data_name_2">
   <div class="_container_">
      <span>P</span>
      <span>L</span>
   </div>
</li>
```

for first array I use following code, but for second array (test) I don't know how should I continue.
The `jQuery(this).data('attr-name')` creates data_name_1, data_name_2 and ...

```
var object_name = {};
  jQuery('li').each(function(){
   object_name[jQuery(this).data('attr-name')] = 'test';
  });
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: You need to show your html, from where those A B came from?

Comment: @jcubic I edited and add HTML. Thank you
May be what I use as code in jquery is false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to find all spans elements with [jQuery::find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) and get the text from that span using [jQuery::text](https://api.jquery.com/text/).

Map will iterate over your selected spans and [jQuery::get](https://api.jquery.com/get/) will return array of strings from jQuery object.

```js
var object_name = {};
$('li').each(function(){
  var li = $(this);
  object_name[li.data('attr-name')] = li.find('span').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get();
});

console.log(object_name);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li data-attr-name="data_name_1">
   <div class="_container_">
       <span>A</span>
       <span>B</span>
   </div>
</li>
<li data-attr-name="data_name_2">
   <div class="_container_">
      <span>P</span>
      <span>L</span>
   </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the elements directly - using `reduce` and `map` as you go:

```js
var result = $('li').get().reduce( (acc,x) => {
  acc[$(x).data("attr-name")] = $(x).find("span").get().map(s => $(s).text());
  return acc;
},{})

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li data-attr-name="data_name_1">
   <div class="_container_">
       <span>A</span>
       <span>B</span>
   </div>
</li>
<li data-attr-name="data_name_2">
   <div class="_container_">
      <span>P</span>
      <span>L</span>
   </div>
</li>
```